How do I invoke my lang key using Handlebars JS inside a Javascript template literal
I'm trying to invoke my lang files (i.e. en.json, es.json, etc.) within a Javascript template literal however, when I call upon the lang file using Handlebars, it renders the lang call as a string instead of converting it into the text in my lang files. How do I change my code to make it pull from the lang files instead? Currently it is displaying the button with {{ lang product.quick_view }} as plain text.
Here is the HTML:
        <div class="quiz">
            <div id="quiz-container">
                <div id="question-container" class="question"></div>
                <ul id="options-container" class="productGrid"></ul>
            </div>
            <ul id="result-container" class="result">
            </ul>
        </div>
    <script src="{{cdn 'assets/js/autoselect-assist.js'}}"></script>

And here is my Javascript:
function displayResults() {
    questionContainer.textContent = "Your recommended product(s):";
    optionsContainer.innerHTML = "";
    
    if (filteredProducts.length > 0) {
        filteredProducts.forEach(result => {
            const productElement = document.createElement("li");
            productElement.classList.add("product");
            productElement.innerHTML += `
                <article class="card" data-event-type="list" data-name="${result.name} data-product-category="" data-product-brand="${result.brand} data-product-price="${result.price}>
                    <figure class="card-figure">
                        <a href="${result.url}" class="card-figure__link" target="_blank" aria-label="${result.name}, ${result.price}" data-event-type="product-click">
                            <div class="card-img-container">
                                <img src="${result.img}" class="card-image lazyautosizes ls-is-cached lazyloaded" alt="${result.name}" title="${result.name}" data-sizes="auto" srcset="${result.img} data-srcset="${result.img}" sizes="285px">
                            </div>
                        </a>
                        <figcaption class="card-figcaption">
                            <div class="card-figcaption-body">
                                <button type="button" class="button button--small card-figcaption-button quickview" data-event-type="product-click">{{ lang "products.quick_view" }}</button>
                                <label class="button button--small card-figcaption-button">
                                {{ lang "products.compare" }}
                                <input type="checkbox" name="products[]">
                                </label>
                                <a href="${result.url}" data-event-type="product-click" class="button button--small card-figcaption-button">{{ lang "products.choose_options" }}</a>
                            </div>
                        </figcaption>
                    </figure>
                    <div class="card-body">
                        <p class="card-text" data-test-info-type="brandName">${result.brand}</p>
                        <h3 class="card-title">
                            <a href="${result.url}" target="_blank">${result.name}</a>
                        </h3>
                        <div class="card-text" data-test-info-type="price">
                        <div class="price-section price-section--withoutTax">
                            <span class="price-label"></span>
                            <span class="price-now-label" style="display: none;"></span>
                            <span data-product-price-without-tax class="price price--withoutTax">$${result.price}</span>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </article>`;
            optionsContainer.appendChild(productElement);
        });
    } else {
      optionsContainer.textContent = "No products match your criteria. Please try again!";
    }

    const restartButton = document.createElement("button");
    restartButton.textContent = "Restart Quiz";
    restartButton.addEventListener("click", restartQuiz);
    restartButton.classList.add("restart", "button", "button--primary");
    optionsContainer.appendChild(restartButton);
}


I don't understand how you are using Handlebars. The productElement.innerHTML += means you are appending the long string containing {{ lang "products.compare" }} directly to your document. At no point are you processing this text with Handlebars in order to for it to evaluate your {{ }} expressions.

Maybe I'm not? I figured the double curly bracket notation was handlebars, using it to call the lang file, it's everywhere in my website's theme, and to as far as I'm aware that's handlebars, but I definitely could be wrong. I don't know how I'm calling the lang file in that case if it's not, I can't find anywhere in the code to see where lang is defined, yet, in other parts of the code, the lang key works fine, just not within an .innerHTML template literal

I suspect that you are rendering your HTML on the server-side using Handlebars, using something like express-handlebars. That's why your {{ }} expressions work in your theme. But here you are constructing HTML on the client-side. You would need to have Handlebars available on the client-side and include your lang helper and the translation files it requires. The other option would be to construct the HTML that you have in your example on the server somehow.
